# Is it safe to throw / catch on stack unwind?

Tags: c++, exception, stack-unwinding

Q: Is it safe to throw and catch an exception on stack unwind, or does the application call `terminate` on the second throw?

minimal example:

```
void some_function()
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff here that can throw
        throw std::runtime_error("blah");
    } catch(const std::exception& re)
    {
        try // this code could be in some function called from here
        {
            // do something with re here that throws a logical_error
            throw std::logical_error("blah blah"); // does this call terminate?
        } catch(const std::logical_error& le)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I got curious after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504166/how-should-one-log-when-an-exception-is-triggered).

Note: I know you can/should `catch(...)` in a destructor, but does it make sense in general to have a `try/catch` in a `catch` block - maybe in some function called on the exception (`re` in my example)?

Comment: That's not really during a stack unwinding though, right? AFAIK, once the `catch` block is entered, the stack has already been unwound.

Comment: Ahh ... thanks :) If you add it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: No need to close, I could be wrong. My comment was more of a guess.

Comment: @Pubby: You're right. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not really during stack unwinding. Once a catch block is entered, the stack has already been unwound.

And yes, that code is legal. See this question: [Nested try...catch inside C++ exception handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711652/nested-try-catch-inside-c-exception-handler)

Comment: Conversely, throwing in a destructor **could** be "on stack unwind".  And there's well-defined behavior specifically for that scenario.

Comment: +1. Yes, when it enters into `catch` block, there is no exception in the flight, which means the `catch` block can throw; the behavior is well-defined. In fact, rethrow (which is allowed from `catch` only) is one kind of throw.

Answer (score 3):

Pubby's answer best answers the scenario you're describing.

As an addendum, while a stack is unwinding, the only user code that's executed is destructors (and the code those destructors call).

If you **do** `throw` in a destructor during this scenario (and don't catch the exception in the same destructor), the standard specifies that `std::terminate()` will be called.

Comment: Not quite. If you throw an exception **that propagates out of the destructor** in this scenario the standard specifies that `std::terminate()` will be called. `try { throw 3; } catch(int) { }` inside a destructor won't lead to `std::terminate()`.